# Eclipse issues with ANT Build

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

So I was working on a project on a different computer(Windows 10) using Eclipse and Proclipsing. I then emailed the file to myself to work on my home computer(Mac 10.10.1)(running Processing through Proclipsing). However, when ever I try to run the program it asks me if I want to run it in an ANT build, which it didn't previously run in. Trying to run it as an ANT build, it tells me "Build Failed. Reason: Unable to Find an ANT file to run." Here's the code for reference:

```
package myfinalproject;
import  java.util.Random;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PFont;


public class MyFinalProject extends PApplet {
    public float speed = 5;
    public float vy=5;
    public float vx=5;
    public float x = 400;
    public float y = 350;
    PFont f;
    public boolean moveleft = false;
    public boolean moveright=false;
    public boolean moveleft2 = false;
    public boolean moveright2=false;
    public void setup() {   
        frameRate(100);
        size(1000, 1000);
        background(0);
        f = createFont("Arial",16,true);
        rectMode(CENTER);
 ellipseMode(CENTER);
 ellipseMode(RADIUS);

        }
    float boxX=500;
    float boxY=950;
    float boxX2=500;
    float boxY2=50;
    float ballX=500;
    float ballY=500;
    float radius=25;
    float ballradius=30;
    float boxheight= 25;
    float boxwidth= 150;
    float player1score=0;
    float player2score=0;
    float boxcdy=boxY+(boxheight/2);
     float boxcdy2=boxY2+(boxheight/2);
     float boxcdx=boxX+boxwidth/2;
     float boxcdx2=boxX2+boxwidth/2;
public void draw(){
background(0);
gametext();
drawellipse();
values();
drawrect();
offscreen();
move();
collision();
gameover();

        }
public void values() {
       boxcdy=boxY+(boxheight/2);
       boxcdy2=boxY2+(boxheight/2);
       boxcdx=boxX+(boxwidth/2);
       boxcdx2=boxX2+(boxwidth/2);
       }

public void gametext(){
    textFont(f,18);
    fill(255);
    text(player1score,500, 50);
    text(player2score, 500,950);

}
public void drawellipse(){
    ellipse(ballX, ballY, radius, radius);
    fill(255,255,255);  

}
public void ballmovement(){
    ballY+=vy;
    ballX+=vx;}
public void collision(){
    if((boxX-75<ballX)&&(ballX<boxX+75)&&(dist(boxX,boxY,ballX,ballY)<radius+(boxheight/2))){
        vx=vx;
        vy=-vy;
    }
    if((boxX2-75<ballX)&&(ballX<boxX2+75)&&(dist(boxX2,boxY2,ballX,ballY)<radius+(boxheight/2))){
        vx=vx;
        vy=-vy;
    }}
public void drawrect(){
    rect(boxX,boxY,boxwidth,boxheight);
    fill(255,255,255);
    rect(boxX2,boxY2,boxwidth,boxheight);
    fill(255,255,255);
}   
public void moveleft(){
    if((moveleft == true)&&(boxX>0)){
        boxX-=speed;}
        if((moveleft2 == true)&&(boxX2>0)){
        boxX2-=speed;}
}   
public void moveright(){
if((moveright == true)&&(boxX<1000)){
boxX+=speed;}
if((moveright2 == true)&&(boxX2<1000)){
boxX2+=speed;}
}   
public void offscreen(){
    if ((ballX>1000)||(ballX<0)){
        vy=-vy;
        vx=-vx;
    }}
public void keyPressed(){

if(key == 'd'){
moveright=true;
}
if(key == 'j'){
moveleft2=true;
}
if(key == 'l'){
moveright2=true;
}   
if(key=='a'){
moveleft=true;}}
public void keyReleased(){
    if(key == 'a'){
        moveleft=false;}
    if(key == 'j'){
        moveleft2=false;}
    if(key == 'l'){
        moveright2=false;}
    if(key=='d'){
        moveright=false;}}
public void move(){
    moveright();
    moveleft();
    ballmovement();
    }
public void gameover(){
    if (ballY>1025){
        player2score=player2score+1;
        ballX=500;
        ballY=500;}
    if(ballY<0){
        player1score=player1score+1;
        ballX=500;
        ballY=500;
    if((player1score>=3)||(player2score>=3)){
        player1score=0;
        player2score=0;
        text("You Won!",300,500);
        ballX=500;
        ballY=500;
        background(0);
        textFont(f,36);
        fill(255);
        text("Welcome to 2 Player Pong!",300,500);
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you choose _not_ to run in ANT build?

Comment: It only gives me the choice of running in ANT build and ANT Build... I've never run in a ANT build before, though. I can only assume it's the Mac vs. Windows change, or a bad installation of Proclipsing.